# Change Timezone from PST to GMT

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have timezone Name 'America/San francisco'

```
NSTimeZone* timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/San francisco"];
```

It gives timeZone in PST. But I need timeZone in GMT as (GMT-8) offset -28800

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `NSTimeZone` method `timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT :` constructs a time zone with a GMT+/- name. Such a time zone does not have any daylight savings period. To construct an offset time zone which is correct for a particular date for Pacific Time you can use `secondsFromGMTForDate:` to obtain the correct offset:

```
NSTimeZone *pacificTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"];
NSDate *targetDate = ...;
NSTimeZone *offsetTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:[pacificTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:targetDate]];
```